# Proving $\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(n!)^2}+2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i(2n)!}{i!(2n-i)!} = 0$ for positive integer $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrix-equations, factorial

> How can I prove that$$\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{(n!)^2}+2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i(2n)!}{i!(2n-i)!} = 0 $$
> for every positive integer $n$?

I came across this identity when trying to prove that the inverse of an exponential matrix is the exponential matrix with the exponent negative, a.k.a. $[e^{\mathbf{A}t}]^{-1} = e^{-\mathbf{A}t} $

Or alternatively, could you help me sketch a simple proof of the mentioned matrix equation?

Comment: Proving that $[e^{\mathbf{A}t}]^{-1} = e^{-\mathbf{A}t}$ is equivalent to proving that $e^{\mathbf{A}t}e^{-\mathbf{A}t} = I$. Doesn't this follow from the fact that $\mathbf{A}t$ and $-\mathbf{A}t$ commute, which permits the exponential law $e^{\mathbf{M}}e^{\mathbf{N}}=e^{\mathbf{M}+\mathbf{N}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a consequence of the binomial theorem:

$$\begin{align*}
0&=(1-1)^{2n}=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^i\binom{2n}i\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{2n}i+(-1)^n\binom{2n}n+\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}(-1)^i\binom{2n}i\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{2n}n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{2n}i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{2n-i}\binom{2n}{2n-i}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{2n}n+2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{2n}i
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: @PabloPadilla: You’re welcome.